# L'utilisation du mot « longtemps »

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, usage, adverbes

Est-ce qu'il y a une règle d'utilisation de cet adverbe ? Je l'ai vu quelques fois écrit avec le mot *pour*.

Par exemple :

> Quand on est mort, c’est pour longtemps.

Par contre, c'est différent dans cette phrase :

> Longtemps le tourisme a été l'affaire des étrangers.

Answer (score 1):

Cet adverbe peut être précédé d'une préposition.

***depuis*** longtemps, ***dès*** longtemps, ***de*** longtemps, ***pendant*** longtemps, ***durant*** longtemps, et, dans le cas qui te préoccupe : ***pour*** longtemps, c'est à dire pour une longue période dans l’avenir.

Comme observé en commentaires, d'autres prépositions peuvent aussi se rencontrer : *après, dans, en, sur*...

Comment: Oui, article amendé en ce sens. Maintenant, je ne connais pas ***avec** longtemps* et soupçonnerai un pb de typo dans les ngrams ou alors la prise en compte d'articles de dictionnaires comme par ex : *longuement a été confondu avec longtemps*

Comment: Très juste, il faut garder à l'esprit ces problèmes d'ambigüité.

Comment: « **de** longtemps » est rare et « **dès** longtemps » l'est encore plus; de plus elles  sont utilisées de moins en moins. On peut ajouter « **après** » et « **dans** » en tant que prépositions utilisées couramment avec « longtemps ». D'après les ngrams il semble que « **en** », « **sur** » et « **avec** » soient aussi des prépositions possibles mais rarement utilisées . **depuis, pendant, durant, pour, dans, après, (de, dès, en, avec, sur)**. Au lieu de « C'est comme ça de longtemps. », qui semble plutôt appartenir à un registre non standard, on dit « Il y a longtemps que c'est comme ça. ».